# Using Memcache, Should I use PDO or an ORM?

Tags: php, caching, pdo, orm

I am working on a project with a custom HTML5 front end and a backend I've designed from experience. The backend is composed of a message queue and a cache - currently I've chosen Beanstalk and Memcache because I'm famliar with them but I am open to suggestions.

My question though comes from how my coder is interfacing with the MySQL DB we are using to store the data. The idea is to pre-cache most or all of the DB so the site runs really fast. It's not a huge DB so RAM for Memcache shouldn't be an issue. However, my coder is using CodeIgniter with GreenBean. I've never heard of GreenBean before and when I google it I get almost nothing that isn't related to greenbeans the food. What little I could find suggested it was an ORM which fits from what my coder has told me.

The problem is this. With raw PDO my pre-caching scheme is simple - I would grab each row from each table and store it in the cache with a key. Then every time I needed that data I would look at the cache first for it and then the DB. If something is changed on the backend then I only need to update that row in the DB and the associated key in the cache.

With an ORM, if I store the entire ORM object serialized into the cache then it holds a bunch of related data. Data that could be incorrect if something were changed. For example, you have a DB of employees that is linked to the office they work in and the dept they work in. The ORM grabs the office and the dept and we store all of that in the cache. But if the office address changes the ORM object for every employee in that office is now stale/incorrect.

In that example, just letting the cache expire probably isn't an issue most of the time. But in my application, that data should really get updated immediately. So in a simple PDO scheme you flush the cache keys related to the data that changed and every future page call gets the updated data. But with an ORM you have lots and lots of cached object instances that might be incorrect and no good way of finding them. So it seems to me you are now left with some form of indexing of your cached objects and when you change something simple you could be flushing and refilling a big chunk of the cache. The site gets really slow then.

Typically I would just cache a DB result after the first time I needed it but in this case I think that could end up being really slow for a lot of users that make the first requests that particular set of data. Additionally, there are some search features that could require a lot of data from the DB. Thus my desire to pre-cache.

So in this case I'm thinking an ORM would hurt the site's performance. I'm thinking I'm not the first person to have this issue though. Is there an ORM out there that would handle this scenario well? Is there a better backend architecture I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Cache invalidation can add all sorts of complexity to an app, so it would be worth checking you absolutely need database caching to start with. The reason of "so the site runs really fast" is popular but usually wrong. Don't do this until you realistically can predict you have a load problem. It sounds like it's not live yet, so could this be premature optimisation?

Comment: It is not live yet. And I hear you on the premature optimization. I've done that to myself more than once. However, the end customer expects the site to see lots of traffic and requires that the front page search form operate as fast as possible. My own assessment is that this is a site the will live or die based on the ease of the UI and speed of service. We are building a beta site in order to learn a few things about the front end UI and how to build the backend better for the full expected load.

Comment: Re your ORM, are you sure you don't mean [RedBean](http://www.redbeanphp.com)?

Comment: My coder has repeatedly mentioned GreenBean and never RedBean. I will double check with him. I have seen a couple of references to GreenBean with CodeIgniter. But only a couple, both CI and GB were mention in them, and they were someone's experience in setting them up not coding references.

Comment: Re searching, this is sometimes done differently to take load off a main database e.g. ElasticSearch, Lucene, a no-SQL solution, or a relational database with denormalised rows.

Comment: I'm not sure it is entirely appropriate for this application but I like the ElasticSearch... built on Lucene... The others will take a little more time to explore. Thanks